# Unable to pull docker image in Rstudio

Tags: r, docker, rstudio

I have trouble pulling a docker image from Rstudio using babelwhale libary. I tried running the command below

```
babelwhale::pull_container("ubuntu:18.04")
```

But it gave the following error

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/images/create?fromImage=ubuntu&tag=18.04: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
Error in processx::run("docker", c("pull", container_id), echo = TRUE) : 
  System command error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using RStudio in a unix system which probably requires root access to pull an image from docker. I think you should try launching Rstudio with sudo privilege from the terminal using the command

```
sudo rstudio
```

and then rerun the babelwhale function above.